# Skip callbacks in amoeba gem while cloning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, amoeba-gem

Consider a basic structure with class A has many B.
Now while cloning A object, I want to skip callbacks of object B. How to do that?
We generally do this using attr_accessor but I unable to do that too.

https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba/issues/17

This issue is opened from a long time.

```
 class File < ApplicationRecord
   amoeba do
     enable
     include_association :attachments
   end
   has_many :attachments
 end

 class Attachment < ApplicationRecord

   attr_accessor :skip_processing

   amoeba do
     enable
     # This is wrong
     set :skip_processing => true
   end

   belongs_to :file

   after_commit :process_attachment, on: :create, unless: :skip_processing
 end
```

There was some error while using attr_accessor in amoeba block, I think we can use only DB values.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Amoeba gem provide different preprocessor and one of it is customize which I used here.
You can pass a lambda function or array of lambda function in which you can call methods or set attributes for the cloned object. I used it to set the attr_accessor as follow -

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord

   attr_accessor :skip_processing

   amoeba do
     enable
     customize (lambda { |original, cloned|
       # Set attr_accessor here
       cloned.skip_processing = true
     })
   end

   belongs_to :file

   after_commit :process_attachment, on: :create, unless: :skip_processing
 end
```